# How to turn a Django QueryDict into a list of Django ORM OR filters?

Tags: django

I would like to turn this: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/fields_data/?field_name__exact=053&field_name__exact=064

into this:

```
fields = Fields.objects.filter(Q(field_name__exact='053')| Q(field_name__exact=field'064))
```

There could be additional numbers of field_name__exacts, it's not known until runtime.

In views.py, I can turn the URL into a QueryDict easily because request.GET is already a QueryDict object. According to the docs, QueryDict was designed in part so that the same key name could be used with multiple values, a common pattern in urls.

I then try to turn the QueryDict into something compatible with **kwargs by using:
`fields = serialize('geojson', Fields.objects.filter(**request.GET.dict()))`, but request.GET.dict() looks like this:
`{'field_name__exact': ['053', '064']}`. As a result, I only ever get back the second object.

I'm starting to suspect I may need to write something more sophisticated involving comprehensions, but I feel like I'm really close. Can someone help me with the correct syntax to turn the QueryDict (multi-valued keys) into an OR'd set of Q()'s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension here:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Fields.objects.filter(
    Q(*[(k,v) for k,vs in request.GET.lists() for v in vs], _connector=Q.OR)
)
```

This will then make a query that makes a logical OR between the items in the `QueryDict`.